# aiokafka: is lock required for processing message when considering consumer group rebalance for kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, aio

when initiating an aiokafka consumer with `ConsumerRebalanceListener`, we have a processing process for the batch of messages(getmany()) received from kafka. We add this processing process to `on_partitions_revoked` as well to make sure these processing will be finished when rebalance occurs.

When rebalance occurs and meanwhile the processing process already occurs the `on_partitions_revoked` will call the processing process again and could process messages twice, to avoid this we add a lock at beginning of this process.

I'm actually not quite sure if we really need the lock in this scenario, so would appreciate if folks here can advise on this. While we use aiokafka for this case I guess this could be a general question for Kafka.

```
class KafkaWrapper(ConsumerRebalanceListener):
    def __init__(
        self,
        consumer_bootstrap_servers: List[str],
        consumer_topic: str,
        consumer_group_id: str,
    ):
        self.records_lock = asyncio.Lock()  
        
        self.kafka_consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=consumer_bootstrap_servers,
            group_id=consumer_group_id,            
        )
        self.kafka_consumer.subscribe(topics=[consumer_topic], listener=self) 

    async def process_records(self):
        async with self.records_lock:  # Is this lock really required??
            # processing message

    async def on_partitions_revoked(self, _revoked):
        await self.process_records()

    async def on_partitions_assigned(self, _assigned):
        pass

    async def _watch_kafka(self):
        await self.kafka_consumer.start()

        while not self.should_stop.is_set():
            messages = await self.kafka_consumer.getmany()
            
            if len(local_records_by_topic_partition) > 0:
                async with self.records_lock:
                    self.messages = messages
                await self.process_records()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you should use `asyncio.lock`

If you don't use `lock`, revoke can occur in the middle of the process.
This can cause unexpected effects on your implementation.
Even worse, if there is a commit method in the process, the following scenario is possible:

process start -> revoke start -> commit -> error !

The error occurs because a consumer lost authority over partitions.

Therefore, by using `lock`, the revoke should occur after the process is completely finished.